# How to resize a QWidget from its center

Tags: c++, qt, resize, qwidget, qlabel

How can I resize a QLabel and be able to retain its current position? What I want to do is basically resize it, but I want this to be resized from all four sides equally instead of resizing from top-left corner. In other words I want to change the resize point of a widget.

I can accomplish what I'm describing above by basically resizing and repositioning the widget once it has been resize but this is a tedious process and I'm wondering if there is a better way.

I'm not sure if I'm explaining this right, I hope it makes sense.

Comment: are you using layouts or is it just inserted into another widget by using setgeometry or move/resize? I guess the second is true so I would just inherit from QLabel and write a derived class that would remember its center position and then override its resizeEvent in which you would use move() with proper coordinates. just beware not to call resize() or setGeometry() inside your resizeEvent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resize and reposition the widget in one go using QWidget::setGeometry(), taking the new position and size as rectangle (QRect). There's no ready-made function for your exact requirement, but you can of course write a little helper function doing the math.